# Grails Permission denied Error

Tags: grails

I am trying to run a Grails application, I checked it out from SVN repo and I get the following errors !

```
Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-mysql-connector-java/tags/RELEASE_5_1_20/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.pom

Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-mysql-connector-java/tags/RELEASE_5_1_20/grails-mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar

Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.20/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.pom

Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.20/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar

Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_2_7_3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom

Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_2_7_3/grails-spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.jar

Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom

Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/1.2.7.3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.jar

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20
- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:1.2.7.3
```

When I try to navigate to the link, it gives me a 404 error. How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Grails is trying to resolve the dependencies. Can you access those URLs from that computer?

Comment: Where in buildConfig are you defining your mysql connector?

Answer (score 0):

Grails is trying to resolve the application's dependencies by automatically downloading them, but for whatever reason is unable to access those sites. You will need to make those dependencies accessible (the easiest way is to install them manually). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12060424/575982) for how to deal with it. That answer was only dealing with the Spring Security Core dependency, but the solution will work for all of your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I was connected with VPN when I got the error, I disconnected from VPN and everything works fine !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having trouble connecting to the repositories. This is probably due to trying to access them from behind a firewall. Configuring a proxy will help solve many of these issues.

```
Example:
grails add-proxy client --host=proxy-server --port=4300 --username=guest --password=guest
grails set-proxy client
```

Read the documentation [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html).