# When added domain class to grails, server access errors

Tags: grails, netbeans

I am trying to do a [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/grails-quickstart.html) in Grails/Netbeans and wound up installing Grails version 2.2.4.  I tried creating a domain class, and I am getting several Server Access Errors:

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.4 | Configuring classpath :: problems summary :: :::: ERRORS   Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat/tags/RELEASE_7_0_52_1/tomcat-7.0.52.1.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-tomcat/tags/RELEASE_7_0_52_1/grails-tomcat-7.0.52.1.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.52.1/tomcat-7.0.52.1.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/7.0.52.1/tomcat-7.0.52.1.zip

| Downloading: C:\grails\grails-2.2.4\dist\grails-plugin-async-2.2.4.jar :: problems summary :: :::: ERRORS     Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-scaffolding/tags/RELEASE_2_0_2/scaffolding-2.0.2.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-scaffolding/tags/RELEASE_2_0_2/grails-scaffolding-2.0.2.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/scaffolding/2.0.2/scaffolding-2.0.2.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/scaffolding/2.0.2/scaffolding-2.0.2.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-cache/tags/RELEASE_1_1_1/cache-1.1.1.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-cache/tags/RELEASE_1_1_1/grails-cache-1.1.1.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/cache/1.1.1/cache-1.1.1.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/cache/1.1.1/cache-1.1.1.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-hibernate/tags/RELEASE_3_6_10_9/hibernate-3.6.10.9.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-hibernate/tags/RELEASE_3_6_10_9/grails-hibernate-3.6.10.9.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/hibernate/3.6.10.9/hibernate-3.6.10.9.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/hibernate/3.6.10.9/hibernate-3.6.10.9.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-database-migration/tags/RELEASE_1_3_8/database-migration-1.3.8.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-database-migration/tags/RELEASE_1_3_8/grails-database-migration-1.3.8.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/database-migration/1.3.8/database-migration-1.3.8.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/database-migration/1.3.8/database-migration-1.3.8.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-jquery/tags/RELEASE_1_11_0_2/jquery-1.11.0.2.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-jquery/tags/RELEASE_1_11_0_2/grails-jquery-1.11.0.2.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.11.0.2/jquery-1.11.0.2.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/jquery/1.11.0.2/jquery-1.11.0.2.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-resources/tags/RELEASE_1_2_7/resources-1.2.7.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-resources/tags/RELEASE_1_2_7/grails-resources-1.2.7.zip

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/resources/1.2.7/resources-1.2.7.pom

    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/resources/1.2.7/resources-1.2.7.zip
```

Any ideas how to get around this?  The closest I see is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060268/grails-installing-a-plugin-from-behind-corporate-firewall-which-blocks-access), but it's different so I'm not sure if it would help me.  Thanks for any help!

Someone asked what the buildConfig.groovy looks like:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.4"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.7"
        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        // An alternative to the default resources plugin is the asset-pipeline plugin
        //compile ":asset-pipeline:1.6.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.5.5"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.5.3"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.5.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: @Don-The buildConfig.groovy has been added to the original question above.

Comment: It looks like it might be a problem with your Internet connection, do you need to connect through a proxy server?

Comment: Also, not that it will fix your problem, your BuildConfig.groovy file is not for Grails version 2.2.4. It is for Grails 2.3.x. Forked execution is a new feature in 2.3. See [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew23) for details. I agree with Don though. Looks like an internet connectivity issue.

Comment: I wonder if 2.3 is showing up because I downloaded 2.3, created the netbeans project, found issues with it missing things in the package, then downloaded 2.2.4, not realizing it created things based on the 2.3 package.  I'll look into the internet connectivity.  Is there a place to setup a proxy server in netbeans?  Web development with groovy/etc is new to me.

Comment: Just to let you know, I went to netbeans, Tools, Options, and when I test my connection, it is failing.  I tried to set it explicitly to Firefox and set up the manual proxy settings for http proxy and it's still failing.  I'll have to figure out what is needed.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I found out from our IT people that there's a different proxy I need to use, different from what's in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a netbeans setup issue.  I needed to configure my proxy differently than it was showing in IE.  Thanks!