# play framework 2.4 oracle

Tags: playframework, oracle10g, playframework-2.4

I have a problem with oracle database:

```
[warn]  module not found: com.oracle#ojdbc6;11.2.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/adrian/.ivy2/local/com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   /home/adrian/projects/com.silenceonthewire.defcollector/repository/com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   /home/adrian/activator-dist-1.3.5/repository/com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0/ojdbc6-11.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0/ojdbc6-11.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving net.contentobjects.jnotify#jnotify;0.94-play-1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.oracle#ojdbc6;11.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
```

what is a current oracle database driver into play 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. 
It seems you need to download & add JDBC driver to your local Ivy repository. 
(As far as I know, there is no public repository with Oracle JDBC drivers)

Or, using sbt, you can also add driver in /lib directory. 
As far as I remember play script was wrapper around sbt, so it may work also this way (to be tested)

EDIT: If you have repository, find in documentation how to add an jar. 
If you are looking for quick & dirty method, to add to your local cache only, you can check [Unable to add jar file to .ivy cache manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314433/unable-to-add-jar-file-to-ivy-cache-manually).